# For each number in an array, find the first smaller number from the left of it

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

I have been thinking about this problem for literally hours, and every idea I have had so far was no good.

The function that does this receives the original array and an empty array that needs to be filled.

If there is no such index for some object, then -1 should be inserted.

For example, for the array: [4,6,8,1,7,10,15,9,11] the array [-1,0,1,-1,3,4,5,4,7] should be returned, because for example if we look at 9 in the original array, the first smaller number from the left of it is 7, and the index of 7 is 4. Therefore instead of 9 in the original array, 4 should be filled in the new one.

If the size of the original array is n, I have a time complexity of O(n) and a space complexity of O(n) as well.

You may only use arrays or lists for help, and not other structures.

Here is what I gathered thus far:
1. Sorting the array, and solutions that in-explicitly do it are not good enough.

2. If we start to look at the array from left to right, once we found a number smaller than some other number, the "other" number can be tossed away. I believe this is the most important thing but I am unable to use it.
3. Dividing the original array into sorted mini-arrays won't help.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. I don't have an idea that will get me started therefore I ask for help, and the problem is stated very clearly.

Comment: I wasn't the one to downvote, but generally speaking you need to show what you have already tried in order for people to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a stack (based on array or list :)). It will keep indexes of candidate elements.

Walk through source array.

If current element is larger than element addressed by stack top, copy stack top into output array and push current index onto stack.

If element addressed by stack top is larger, pop stack until smaller one is found.

I omitted some moments to realize by yourself.

Note that at every moment stack contains indexes of increasing sequence.

Comment: I had a very similar idea and didn't notice that it will be good enough. Thank you.